# Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, switch-statement

Why Do I get this error? 
Switch statement doesn't return cell?
Can somebody explain this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LogoStyle1", for: indexPath) as! LogoStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FieldStyle1", for: indexPath) as! FieldStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonStyle1", for: indexPath) as! ButtonStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to return the cell in the default statement.

Comment: default: return UITableViewCell()

Comment: Why this is needed?

Comment: @John, because of `cellForRowAt` func definition.

Comment: @John, because the method __must return__ an instance of the `UITableViewCell` class.

Comment: Who downvotes for this question shame on you.

Comment: It's a newbie-level question. Perhaps somebody thinks you shouldn't be able to ask such questions? To me, it seems like a valid question at your level of understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those things that the compiler gets over-worried about. The compiler is basically asking you, what if `indexPath.row` is neither 0 nor 1 nor 2? What to return in that case. As the programmer you know that `indexPath.row` will always be one of those values, but the compiler doesn't know that.

So you need to return something in the `default` case, but it does not make sense to return anything, does it? In this case, I would just write:

```
fatalError("Somehow indexPath.row is an unexpected value.")
```

This will crash the app if the `default` case is ever reached. If the default case is ever reached, it probably means there is something wrong with your code (or maybe a bug in the API (unlikely)!), because as you know the table view only has 3 rows. The app should probably crash at this point.

Comment: Also I need to remove break statement in this case right. İt is unnecessary.

Comment: @John You don't need `break` at the end of a case in Swift. Just write `fatalError` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @John Another option is to remove the case 2  and move its code to the default. Btw `UIColor` is redundant. `cell.backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: I consider .clear . Thank you. Someone down votes thşs question but it really helped me. You guys please upvote the question so that other people in my case can understand.

Comment: Yes but it really helped me . And learn new way og removing case 2 and move it to defuault.

Answer (score 1):

**CellForRowAtIndexPath** delegate method return cell even when the **numberOfRowsInSection** is 0. So in default block of swicth you need to return a cell.
and error will be gone.